# 0403-057 Syntax error: `;' is not expected

Tags: unix, unix-socket

```
if 
[ -d patch/tempatch ];
then;
cd patch/tempatch/;

for i in `ls`;
do;
tar -xvf $i;
rm -f $i;
done;

for i in `ls`;
do;
cd $i;
cp -R files/* patch/SP02JUL11/files/;
cd ..;
rm -Rf $i;
done;

else;
echo "directory not found";
fi
```

All the commands in single line by separating with ";"

While executing it throws `0403-057 Syntax error: ; is not expected`

can anyone help on this ?

Thank you

Comment: First good step would be to indent the code. I am sure then it will be pretty easy to find out where the problem is.

Comment: if you have created code in Windows, and moved to linux, do `dos2unix myScript`. Good luck.

Comment: I am writing caode in java and executing in UNIX system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specified which shell is interpereting this script... From error code I assume it's *ksh*...

From the error message, I presume that the problem is that after `then`, `else`, `do`, *ksh* does not accept a `;`.

However, just out of curiosity, I did just install ksh on my linux box.
It's at version "93u+ 2012-08-01".
Your script runs just fine, no syntax errors, here...
Probably you are running a different (possibly older) version of the shell, or a different shell at all... You should definitely specify which shell you're using... :-).

Comment: i am using ksh shell only

Comment: os Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

Comment: It's quite strange, I'm on a Centos Release 6.5... However, if you enter each command on a different line (as I see from your code), you can avoid semicolons at all... Semicolons are intended to separate commands on the same line... In particular they are *requested* before a `do`, a `then`, an `else`, but they are *forbidden* after the same commands... I would say ksh (but bash too) is quite 'choosy'... :-)